# How to show clock and battery info in PowerShell terminal?

Tags: windows, powershell

In Windows 11 using the regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon=> Shell` I replaced the desktop with PowerShell. Now when I boot Windows, I only use PowerShell. I like it, but now I can't see the battery level and the clock. How to solve this problem correctly? I would like the battery and the clock to be visible from the side on the edge of the command shell.

Working environment:
[image: working environment]

Comment: Your question is not clear, your description makes it sound like you replaced File Explorer with PowerShell and now you want to have a Taskbar icon showing the status of your battery but the taskbar is a feature of File Explorer not PowerShell. Please edit your question with enough details so it can be answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your prompt? e.g.:

```
function prompt { 
  "PS " + $(get-location) `
  + " [$(Get-Date)]"      `
  + " [$((wmic path win32_battery get estimatedchargeremaining | select -index 2).trim())%] "
}
```

Prompt:

```
PS C:\path\to\pwd [05/12/2023 08:32:05] [96%]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same clock and battery icons as in explorer. It's impossible. Well, maybe some other terminal app could have such icons implemented and you could run that instead, but I doubt there's any currently available.

A workaround is to get the battery level and clock through other means, e.g. [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/) configured to show it in prompt areas.

With that you can enable and configure:

- [battery segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/battery)
- [time segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/time)

Simpliest config example:

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json
final_space: true
version: 2
blocks:
  - type: prompt
    alignment: left
    segments:
      - type: time
        style: plain
      - type: battery
        style: plain
        template: "{{ if not .Error }}{{ .Icon }}{{ .Percentage }}{{ end }}{{ .Error }}"
      - type: path
        style: plain
        template: " {{ .Path }}>"
```

And you can then run `oh-my-posh` with your configuration in your `$PROFILE` `.ps1` config file by adding this line to it:

```
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config C:/path/to/your/config.yml | Invoke-Expression
```